# How to import a text file to MySQL direct or through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to import my text file to MySQL which has only one field. It is like this:

[image]

I could also do this with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mysql **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE** syntax

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.txt' 
    INTO TABLE 'table1'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

For this, make sure `Mysql` has access to `/path/to/file.txt`. Also the user who is executing the query must have *FILE* privilege.

With Pure PHP its easy. Read the file, build the query, execute it.
You need to build the query so that you dont end up looping query which is slow.

```
$data = file("/path/to/file.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// make sure you have valid database connection prior to this point.
// otherwise mysql_real_escape_string won't work
$values = "('". implode("'), ('", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data)). "')";

$query = "INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`COLUMN1`) VALUES $values";

// Now just execute the query once.
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Why all of you use `preg_split?` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php doesn't work anymore or what?

Comment: `I used it because there could be empty entries.

Comment: You're welcome .) (and I'm sorry if I sound rude, didn't mean to)... Those regexp solution are good, but programmers often forgot that they can use much more effective procedural/sequential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use some regex to basically split it up by new lines, ie.

```
$array = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", file_get_contents("path/to/file.txt"));
```

and then do a `foreach` loop, ie:

```
foreach($array as $line){
   // insert into database
}
```

Then all you need to do is fill the line above where you insert it into the correct field in the database, line by line - but please sanitize each line, just so you don't inject the database with anything bad!

Comment: You should probably use `preg_split` instead of explode to account for differing newline characters across operating systems: `$lines = preg_split("[\r\n]+", $txt);`

Comment: I'm a moron and left out the pattern delimiters, so you might wanna update one more time. `"[\r\n]+"` should be `"/\r?\n/"` ... I edited the pattern to make it a bit more useful as well.

Comment: Haha - should have spotted that myself!

Answer (score 1):

#### Using csv import in phpMyAdmin

phpMyAdmin supports [CSV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) import, look at [this article](http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2007/05/19/import-a-csv-file-to-mysql-via-phpmyadmin/) for more details (first result after: [`phpMyAdmin csv`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=phpmyadmin%20csv))

#### Using mysqlimport

Mysql provides CLI application, [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html), example usage (again CSV):

```sh
mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=, \
    --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password \
    YOUR_DATABASE YOUR_TABLE.csv
```

#### Mysql `LOAD DATA`

Mysql itself (client, query) supports [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) command, example syntax:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

#### Build sql query with php (and insert manually)

You will parse text file in php and output will be one large `INSERT` statement (this will be useful when/if you cannot connect to mysql from the server where you're running the script:

```php
// This will escape values correctly
function escapeValues( &$val){
    // mysql_real_escape_string is not an option (remote server not accessible
    // in this case)
    return "'" . addslashes( $val) . "'"; 
}

$fp = fopen( $filename, 'r') or die( 'Cannot open');
$result = array();
while( $row = fgets( $fp)){
    $values = explode( '/', $row);
    array_walk( $values, 'escapeValues');
    $results[] = '(' . implode( ', ', $values) . ')';
}

fclose( $fp);

if( !count( $results){
   die();
}

echo 'INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, ... colN) VALUES ';
echo implode( ",\n", $results);
echo "\n";
```

#### Direct connection and direct import

This should be the best approach for you.

```php
$conn = mysql_connect( ...) or die(...);
mysql_select_db(...);

// Now we need to build small class which will allow us escape values properly
// mysql_escape_string is DEPRECATED and mysql_real_escape_string
// requires connection parameter
// Ps: choose better name
class CallbackHack {
    public $connection = null;
    public function escapeValue( &$val){
        $val = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $val, $this->connection) . "'";
    }
}
$hack = new CallbackHack();
$hack->connection = $conn;

$fp = fopen( $filename, 'r') or die( 'Cannot open');
mysql_query( 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;'); // Increases insert performance for InnoDb
while( $row = fgets( $fp)){
    $values = explode( '/', $row);
    array_walk( $values, array( $hack, 'escapeValue'));
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, ... colN) VALUES (' .
            implode( ', ', $values) . ');';
    mysql_query( $sql);
}

mysql_query( 'COMMIT;'); // Make sure it will run
fclose( $fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = preg_split("[\r\n]+", file_get_contents("path/to/file.txt"))

foreach ($array as $line) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `dbname` (colmun1) VALUES ('$line')");
}
?>
```

Always sanitize too !

Comment: It's not safe to copy/paste code from other answers! The `preg_split` pattern needs delimiters! See the last comment on the other answer.

Comment: yeah dial up for the win, the only answer there was his first one when i started writing... sorry...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);


$file = fopen("welcome.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    //Output a line of the file until the end is reached

    while(!feof($file))
      {

$data = mysql_real_excape_string(fgets($file));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (filedata)
VALUES ($data)");
//make sure above query is right according to your table structure
      }
    fclose($file);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```