# How to insert mass amounts of data into SQL table

Tags: mysql, text-files

So I have a pretty simple table in mySQL that has columns `username` and `password`. Both are `VARCHAR` and are large enough to support any entry.

I then have a .txt file with a large number of records.

The txt file is in the format user:pass and looks like:

anon@gmail.com:abcde
....
etc.

I'm wondering how I can insert all the values into my table in mySQL from the .txt file, keeping in mind they're in the format username:password.

Thanks!

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ... FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to import txt to mysql direct or through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250330/how-to-import-txt-to-mysql-direct-or-through-php)

Comment: Please don't store passwords in the database. Use hashing and salt.